# Spring @RequestParam vs @ModelArribute when getting a java.util.Date

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a situation where the following code correctly gets the Date, without the time:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pdf", method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public void printPdf(@RequestParam("printDateTime") Date printDateTime  .... more) {
    printDateTime; // contains date, but NOT the time
    ...more code here...
}
```

However, when I use modelAttribute, it will correctly get the date AND the time from the client.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pdf", method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public void printPdf(@ModelAttribute WorkerSearchParamsDto searchParamsDto  .... more) {

   searchParamsDto.getPrintDateTime(); // Returns correct date with client time...
   ...more code here...
}
```

I am a little confused about why that would be the case and what I could do to resolve this.  There are reasons we would like to not use modelAttribute for the print date, be we can work around it. Any ideas would be helpful.

To be clear, we WANT the time, not just the Date

We are running Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: There is a difference in the code besides the annotation - `Date` for the first fragment and `WorkerSearchParamsDto` for the second. Have you tried to use `Date` for both?

Comment: What does `WorkerSearchParamsDto` contain?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev So was trying to use ONLY the RequestParam method originally. When I added the date value to the DTO it started getting the time correctly. The value coming from the client was the same in both cases.

Comment: @RaulRene "WorkerSearchParamsDto" is just a POJO, straight getters and setters.

Comment: I think the difference must in the way `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s resolve the value for the argument since both arguments are supported by different resolvers.